# Реализация некоторых компонентов css без функционала JS

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Хотел бы узнать у более опытных. Есть ли смысл верстать такие вещи, как *модальные окна, карусели, слайдеры и т.п.*, без использования **js**. Рационально ли это?

Comment: Не рационально - практически везде используется js; решений много и они оптимальны и по коду и по визуализации и по нагрузке.
Если речь чисто о верстке, а остальное на усмотрение кодера, то смысл есть - он реализует все в одном стиле и одной базе, что несомненно будет оптимальным для проекта.
С другой стороны, показать наглядно часто очень пользительно - в общем, в каждом случае нужно смотреть - если все документировано и понятно, то лучше разделять, думается, если дальнейшие этапы выполняются другими.

Comment: По ситуации. Если с точки зрения производительности, то при равных условиях CSS несравнимо быстрее JS. Но если речь о каких-то одиночных вещах (раз загрузился и работает), то CSS имеет смысл только если JS сложнее, тупее, или требует подгрузки лишних библиотек. Конечно можно и стилями так затормозить браузер, что процессор задымится, но если делать по уму, то CSS обычно лучше.